# VS 2008 C# set focus to only one form

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio-2008, focus

When my form (AboutForm) is shown I need to hold the focus on this form (the user should only be able to click the OK button) !

Which setting is neccessary in VS2008?

Thanks!

greets leon22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to show it *modally*, so use [`ShowDialog()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swcta4hh.aspx) rather than `Show()`. That is all.

For example:

```
using(var frm = new AboutForm()) {
    frm.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

important: when using `ShowDialog`, closing the form does not `Dispose()` it, hence the `using`; see MSDN:

> Unlike modeless forms, the Close method is not called by the .NET Framework when the user clicks the close form button of a dialog box or sets the value of the DialogResult property. Instead the form is hidden and can be shown again without creating a new instance of the dialog box. Because a form displayed as a dialog box is hidden instead of closed, you must call the Dispose method of the form when the form is no longer needed by your application.

Comment: @Marc Gravell A-ha, good thing you mentioned that. Also a good thing, the GC that cleans up after my ignorance :)